# Saving and loading an autoencoder

Tags: python, neural-network, pyspark, prediction, autoencoder

I am trying to make a predictor using **Auto Encoder (AE)** and  **Alternating Least Squares (ALS)** methods.
ALS is created using **pyspark.mllib.recommendation** package. I am able to save the ALS model and reuse it by model.save() and pyspark.mllib.recommendation.MatrixFactorizationModel.load() methods.

AE is created using torch.nn.Module package and has 4 layers.Unlike ALS for AE saving and loading model is not something  I am missing.Can anyone help me to find a way to save and load an auto encoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The torch module provides save and load methods.

It saves the model as .pth files

```
torch.save(model,'model.pth')
```

It also has load method

```
torch.load(.pth_file)
```